Expectation of the product of GBM and Stochastic Integral
Could you please offer some guidance on how to calculate this expectation?  $$ \mathbb E \left[ y_T \cdot \int_0^T y_s \, dW_s\right]$$ where $W_t$ is Wiener prosess and $y_t = y_0 e^{(\mu - \sigma^2/2) t \, + \, \sigma W_t}$ is  GBM process. I try to use the fact that $y_T = \int_0^T dy_s + y_0$ and then replace integrand ("$dy$") by $dy_t = \mu y_t dt + \sigma y_t dW_t $  but with no success. I also found equation   $$\mathbb E \left[ e^{\sigma W_s} \int_0^T e^{\sigma W_u} dW_u\right] = \sigma \int_0^T \mathbb E[e^{2\sigma W_u}] du  $$ but I cannot directly apply it.
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

The solution was found using Kurt G.'s answer to a related question How to compute the expectation of $e^{W_t}\int_0^t e^{-W_s} dW_s$
Note that
$$M_t = e^{\sigma W_t \, - \, \frac{\sigma^2}{2} t}$$ is a martingale that satsifes the SDE $$ dM_t = \sigma M_t \, d W_t$$ Therefore $$M_T = 1 + \sigma \int_0^T M_s \, dW_s$$ Then the calculation of original expectation is equivalent to calculating the following expression:
$$y_0^2 \, \sigma \, e^{\mu \,   T} \, \mathbb E \left [\int_0^T M_s dW_s \int_0^T e^{ \left(\mu \, - \, \frac {\sigma^2}{2} \right)s} e^{\sigma W_s} dW_s \right]$$ Using Ito isometry it reduses to  $$y_0^2 \, \sigma \, e^{\mu T} \int_0^T e^{(\mu  -\sigma^2) s} \, \mathbb E \left[ e^{2 \sigma W_s} \right] ds$$ Using the fact $$\mathbb E \left [e^ {\alpha W_s} \right] = e^ {\frac {\alpha ^2 t}{2}}$$ finally we have $$ \mathbb E \left[ y_T \cdot \int_0^T y_s \, dW_s\right] = \sigma y_0^2 e^{\mu T} \, \cdot \frac{e^{\left( \mu + \sigma^2\right)T}-1}{\mu + \sigma^2}$$
